# peewee using 't1' as table and not my table

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, peewee

I'm new to peewee and can't seem to figure out how to correctly send a query.

Here's my Meta:

```
class Meta:
    database = db
    db_table = 'profile'
```

To my understanding, I told peewee to use the table 'profile'

But when I try to select from the table with:

```
Profile.get(Profile.name == user)
```

I always get an error that is referring to the table 't1' and not my table 'profile'

How do I tell peewee to use a specific table and NOT t1?

Answer (score 0):

Peewee uses aliases when constructing queries, so although it's referring to "t1", the query itself will probably look like:

```
SELECT * FROM "profile" AS "t1" WHERE "t1"."name" = '<whatever>';
```